# FluentValidation: Is it possible to prevent validation of children?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

So I have a Parent object and it has a Children collection which I do not want validated. I already have a ChildValidator set up to validate each child when that child is created/updated. But because of the ChildValidator whenever I save a Parent, it runs the validation for the Children. Is it possible to specify that I do not want the children validated?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide your related codes.

Comment: I think you can have two independent validators, one is for parent and the other is for the child.

Comment: Can you provide more info? Is the validation being performed in an ASP.NET MVC/ASP.NET Core web application as part of the MVC validation pipeline? Or as part of a `Validate` invocation? What does your validator for the parent look like? Do you have `ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties` set to true? There could be a number of solutions but we need more info/example of what you've done so far.